# Display header and footer in every page is breaks by long table

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

I want to set all header and footer in all page in a pdf with mpdf,

So, my code looked like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data Category</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .page{
            padding-top:2.5cm;
            padding-right:1.5cm;
            padding-left:1cm;
            padding-bottom:5cm;
        }
        table{
            border-spacing:0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width:100%;
            page-break-inside:auto;
        }


        table td, table th{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">

        <table border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Tanggal</th>
                    <th>Jam</th>
                    <th>No struk</th>
                    <th>Nama</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Nama Item</th>
                    <th>Harga Jual</th>
                    <th>Sub total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <?php
                $no = 1;
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $no++ ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['date_format'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['jam'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['struk_no'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['nama_karyawan'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['jumlah_jual'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['nama_item'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['harga_jual'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['subtotal'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have alread read their docs from here : [mpdf docs](https://mpdf.github.io/tables/table-layout.html).

But, when my table is loaded more than one page, the table breaks the header:

```
$detail = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($this->getSqlReportDetail($parseStart, $parseEnd))->queryAll();
    $html = $this->renderPartial('_report_detail', ['data' => $detail]);
    $mpdf = new \mPDF('c', 'A4', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list
    $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader(''
            . '<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">'
            . '<h1>Hair Deeper Salon</h1><br>'
            . '<hr>'
            . '</div>'
    );

    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
            <table width="100%" style="vertical-align: bottom; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">{DATE j-m-Y}</span></td>
                    <td width="33%" align="center" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">{PAGENO}/{nbpg}</td>
                    <td width="33%" style="text-align: right; ">My document</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    ');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
```

This is the document right now :
[image: document]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this before setting header and footer

```
$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';
$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
```